# How to apply singe value over different fields in column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have an example table called table1 that looks like this:

```
id       value 
123      X
123      Z
123      B
456      X
456      A
...etc
```

Essentially what I want to do is creaTe a script that will look at each id and the values associated with it. if any of the values are NOT X or Z, apply it over the id in a new column. It would look something like this:

```
id     value  new_value
123    X      B
123    Z      B
123    B      B
456    X      A
455    A      A
```

For IDs that don't have any other values apart from X or Z then just apply those same ones over the new_value column

Comment: What should the value be when there is no `'X'`/`'Y'`?  The question is not clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `then just apply those same ones over the new_value column` ... presumably just pull over the original values, either X or Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could a conditional aggregation approach here using `MAX` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    value,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN value NOT IN ('X', 'Z') THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) = 0
         THEN value
         ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN value NOT IN ('X', 'Z') THEN value END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) END AS new_value
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(max(case when value not in ('X', 'Z') then value end) over (partition by id),
                value
               )
from t;
```

I'm not sure if the `else` clause should be `value` or `max(value) over (partition by id)`.

Comment: @Scratte . . . I fixed the syntax.